# Alert box from function

Tags: javascript

The function is working great but Im missing why my alert box wont trigger after the click.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getRNG(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
  function rollD20() {
    document.getElementById("txtNumber").value = getRNG(1, 20);
  }
  if (txtNumber < 10) {
    alert("Failure");
  } else {
    alert("Success");
  }
</script>

<body>
  <input type="text" disabled="disabled" size="2" id="txtNumber" />
  <div id="output"></div>
  <button onclick="rollD20();">Roll</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because the code is outside the `rollD20()` handler instead of inside.

Comment: But even if it were inside, there's no variable `txtNumber `

Comment: @Jamiec: Technically there is since the `<input id="txtNumber">` will show up as a global, though it's certainly not what he wants there.

Comment: To those being pedantic. Stop being pedantic. You know the `txtNumber` that the browser creates shoeld neither be used nor would contain the value the OP expects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a closure issue. Should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getRNG(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
  function rollD20() {
    document.getElementById("txtNumber").value = getRNG(1, 20);
    if (txtNumber < 10) {
        alert("Failure");
    }
    else {
        alert("Success");
    }
  }
</script>
```

The change was moving the closing bracket for the `rollD20` function to be below your if/else statement.

Also worth noting, I don't see anywhere that you set `txtNumber`.

Perhaps what you meant was:

```
  function rollD20() {
    var txtNumber = getRNG(1, 20);
    document.getElementById("txtNumber").value = txtNumber;
    if (txtNumber < 10) {
        alert("Failure");
    }
    else {
        alert("Success");
    }
  }
```

If so, this could be further reduced (if so desired) to simply:

```
  function rollD20() {
    var txtNumber = document.getElementById("txtNumber").value = getRNG(1, 20);
    alert(txtNumber < 10 ? "Failure" : "Success");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't put it into the `rollD20` function, so the `if-else` logic run only once, when the page loaded. To trigger it on every click, you must put it in the click event handler, like this:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getRNG(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
  function rollD20() {
    var txtNumber = document.getElementById("txtNumber").value = getRNG(1, 20);
    if (txtNumber < 10) {
      alert("Failure");
    } else {
      alert("Success");
    }
  }
</script>

<body>
  <input type="text" disabled="disabled" size="2" id="txtNumber" />
  <div id="output"></div>
  <button onclick="rollD20();">Roll</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I defined a variable named `txtNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

well, the `if...else` logic is outside the function, but you probably want to store the result of `getRND()` in a variable  too:

```
function rollD20() {
    var result = getRNG(1, 20);
    document.getElementById("txtNumber").value = result;  
    if (result < 10) {
      alert("Failure");
    }
    else {
      alert("Success");
    }
  }
```